# Function don't return value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have some snippet of code

```
 for(var i=0; i < this.arr2.length; i++) {
      arr.push({
          id: i.toString(),
          label: this.arr2[i],
          display: () => this.arr2[i]
      })
  }
```

Why is the display undefined if i am doing something like this

```
let val = this.arr2[i];
display: () => val
```

is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `let` keyword in order to declare a block `scope` local **variable**

```
for(let = 0; i < this.arr2.length; i++) {
  arr.push({
      id: i.toString(),
      label: this.arr2[i],
      display: () => this.arr2[i]
  })
}
```

For this example it is easily to use `map` method.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
arr=arr2.map(function(item,i){
   return {id:i,label:item,display:()=>item};
});
```

Short example:

```js
arr2=[1,2,3,4,5];
arr=arr2.map(function(item,i){
       return {id:i,label:item,display:()=>item};
});
console.log(arr[1].display());
```